# How to fix bad window path name error in simpledialog tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Considering a basic app which is a class inheriting from `tk.Tk`, I get an unexpected error message when using the `simpledialog` module from `tkinter`. It is related to overriding the `__str__` method in this class as the `simpledialog` does work without the string override, so my guess would be the `simpledialog` expects default behavior there. See the error message below:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\**\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\**\bad_window_error.py", line 22, in start_dialog
    result = simpledialog.askstring('Simple dialog', 'Fill in a string..')
  File "C:\**\Python39\lib\tkinter\simpledialog.py", line 399, in askstring
    d = _QueryString(title, prompt, **kw)
  File "C:\**\Python39\lib\tkinter\simpledialog.py", line 376, in __init__
    _QueryDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
  File "C:**\Python39\lib\tkinter\simpledialog.py", line 271, in __init__
    Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title)
  File "C:\**\Python39\lib\tkinter\simpledialog.py", line 138, in __init__
    self.transient(parent)
  File "C:\**\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2225, in wm_transient
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'transient', self._w, master)
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name "random"
```

I have put together a minimal example, see below. The actual code I am working on is much bigger with many dependencies and so far I have only noticed this error occurring with the `simpledialog` module.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import simpledialog, messagebox

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Random app')
        self.option_add('*tearOff', False)

        self.start_dialog_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Run simple dialog', command=self.start_dialog)
        self.start_dialog_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

    def __str__(self):
        return "random"

    @staticmethod
    def start_dialog():
        messagebox.showinfo('hello', 'this works')
        result = simpledialog.askstring('Simple dialog', 'Fill in a string..')
        messagebox.showinfo('Result', result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

If the string override is commented out, the code should run as expected. **Is there a way to use the `simpledialog` module while still overriding the default `__str__` method of `tk.Tk` or should I never do that?**

Comment: Your code works fine in my Windows 10 with Python 3.10.3.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by overriding the `__str__` method?

Comment: I would like to use `print(app)` to print information. It is easy to make another method for it. I was especially curious why everything seems to work when overriding `__str__`, except for the `simpledialog`.

Answer (score 0):

IT's better not to override the default functions ;
If you're looking to do it to change the output results, it can easily be done without creating extra issues.

```
@staticmethod
def start_dialog():
    messagebox.showinfo('hello', 'this works')
    result = simpledialog.askstring('Simple dialog', 'Fill in a string..')
    
    if (result is None or result == '') :
        result="random"
    
    else:
        result=result+" this should work"
    messagebox.showinfo('Result', result)
```